# Unit Test Angular Controller Init Code?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-controller

I have a service that is invoked first thing by a controller.  I can't figure out a way to test it with jasmine 1.3.

I cant spy on the productService instance 'fetch' method because by the time the test is written (i think) all the initialization code has been run.

Controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('my.module')
        .controller('MyController', [
            '$scope',
            '$rootScope',
            'ProductService',
            'broadcastEventsConstants',
            'OrganizationSvc',
            function ($scope, $rootScope, ProductService, broadcastEventsConstants, OrganizationSvc) {
                $scope.productService = new ProductService();

                var fetchFresh = function(org) {
                    $scope.productService.filterOptions.page = 0;
                    $scope.productService.org = org;
                    $scope.productService.fetch({append: false, reselect: false});
                }

                var init = function() {
                    if(_.has(OrganizationSvc.selectedOrganization, 'id')) {
                        fetchFresh(OrganizationSvc.selectedOrganization);
                    }
                };

                init();
            }]);
})();
```

}

Tests:

```
'use strict';
describe('MyController', function () {
    var $scope;
    var $rootScope;
    var $controller;
    var MyController
    var ProductService;
    var broadcastEventsConstants;
    var OrganizationSvc;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('my.module', function ($provide) {
            $provide.factory('OrganizationSvc', function () {
                return {
                    selectedOrganization: {
                        id: 1,
                        getList: function (endpoint, options) {
                            console.log('i was called with ', endpoint, options);
                        }
                    }
                };
            });

            $provide.factory('ProductService', function () {
                function ProductService() {
                    this.filterOptions = {};
                    this.fetch = function () {
                        return [];
                    };
                }

                return ProductService;
            });

            $provide.constant('broadcastEventsConstants', {
                ORGANIZATION_CHANGED: 'organizationChanged'
            });
        });
        inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_, _$timeout_, _OrganizationSvc_, _ProductService_, _broadcastEventsConstants_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $controller = _$controller_;
            ProductService = _ProductService_;
            broadcastEventsConstants = _broadcastEventsConstants_;
            OrganizationSvc = _OrganizationSvc_;
        });

        ManagePublishProductController = $controller('ManagePublishProductController', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
    });

    describe('initiating phase', function () {
        it('should make a call to fetch if the org is set on the org service', function () {
            spyOn($scope.productService, 'fetch');
            $scope.$digest();
            expect($scope.productService.fetch).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you create `ProductService` with `new` operator instead of using injected one?

Comment: @fracz its because ProductService has to be instantiated.  It returns a constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `ProductService` has `fetch` declared on its prototype.  You should be able to spy on the prototype method like this:

```
spyOn(ProductService.prototype, 'fetch');
```

If this is not the case, then please include a sketch of what your `ProductService` looks like.